# How to implement a design with react-spring?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, react-spring

In the project's repo the react-redux app is set with CSS in JS files. Now I'm supposed to animate pictures with mouse hover just like this website : https://www.madwell.com/

The component was initially a functional component and I have changed that to a class based component as follows:

```

```
class BannerContainer extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };

    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
  }

  handleMouseMove({ x, y }){
    this.setState({
      x : x / window.innerWidth,
      y : y / window.innerHeight
    })
  }

  render(){
  const { banner = {} } = this.props;

  const {
    title = '&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;',
    text = '&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;',
    image__google_350x80 = '',
    image__app_350x80 = '',
    image__bg1_1166x1878 = '',
    image__bg2_961x1782 = '',
    image__curve_730x151 = ''
  } = banner;

  return (
    <Container>
      <BGPatch>
        {console.log(this.state.x , this.state.y)}
        <img src={'/images/bg_purple.jpg'} alt="" />
      </BGPatch>
```

```

In this example I am able to get listen to the `mouse-move` event and and get the x & y coordinates accordingly. But now I have to use `react-spring` library to implement it so how do I do that? Also the CSS should be written in separate JS file for each component where as in `react-spring` example they directly modify the `opacity` or `trasform` in the Spring component directly as well which is what I don't want

the spring component example given on their docs

```
<Spring from={{ opacity: 0 }} to={{ opacity: 1 }}>
  {props => <div style={props}>hello</div>}
</Spring>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parallaxing effects are relatively easy to do if you have mouse coordinates, here's an example with a similar effect: https://twitter.com/0xca0a/status/1058505720574959616

It uses hooks, but the same thing applies to a regular spring. Though this is probably a good example even, because it doesn't re-render the component on mousemove, which is very fast. You wouldn't use rotates in your case, translates i guess, but the point is, you receive x/y and use it to interpolate your images into position.

EDIT:
I've forked the example, this version uses translates: https://codesandbox.io/embed/r5x34869vq